# Toilet Flush Valve does not always re-seat

Tags: toilet

An older toilet's flush valve does not always (approximately one in ten flushes) does not seat after flushing.  The remedy is to gently jiggle the handle so that it seats and it immediately creates a proper seal.

This was not a problem until 2 months after the valve and chain was replaced.  It worked perfectly for the first 2 months.  Is there a common failure-mode that causes this problem.  No chlorine is used in the tank reservoir.

Comment: Are you speaking about the flap at the bottom of the tank that seals after the water starts to re-fill? Often, this can be caused by the chain that pulls the flap open getting stuck on something. Pop the lid off next time and identify if this is the case. It's also possible that the chain angle is incorrect, and offsetting the flap a tiny bit so it doesn't seal until you jiggle it.

Comment: Chlorine tablets in tank cause rapid deterioration of flapper.  Chain connecting flapper to handle gets a link hung up shortening it jiggle releases hung up link

Comment: @Kris I agree with the chlorine, but OP didn't mention that, and I highly doubt that a tablet would degrade a flap within two months (OP mentioned it had been replaced within that timeframe).

Comment: Is the flap chain corroded? Is the flush handle tightened securely to the reservoir?